# How to know which assemblies are depended on system.web.mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm using asp.net mvc 4 in my project, but there are some assemblies that are trying to find 3.0.0.0.
Project works fine on my development machine, but throws an error "Could not load System.Web.Mvc version 3.0.0.0" on the server.

Also, I see the warning in my Visual Studio

> Found conflicts between different versions of the same dependent
>   assembly. In Visual Studio, double-click this warning (or select it
>   and press Enter) to fix the conflicts; otherwise, add the following
>   binding redirects to the "runtime" node in the application
>   configuration file:

I don't want to add binding redirect in my web.config, I want to update the assembly that depend on older version of system.web.mvc to the newer one, but I have no idea what is the name of that assembly. How can I know that?

Comment: Check the references for your project, select `System.Web.Mvc` and check the version in the properties window.  If it's not right, remove it and add it again but choose v4.0.0.0 instead of v.3.0.0.0

Answer (score 1):

Delete the reference to System.Web.Mvc in the Solution references. Then add only the reference of MVC Ver 4.0 Dll from project folder path - \packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.4.0\lib\net40.

Once you compile the project, It will list out the controller or views which are not compatible with MVC 4.0. You can identify the assemblies based on error details.